# PayPal Express Checkout - Pay a different merchant using app's api credentials

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to enable a paypal transaction so that a buyer using an app can use that app's api credentials, but pay a different seller (not the account of the author of app)?

This most likely is similar to how Shopify would work, except the app would not like to collect/store any of the seller's paypal api credentials.

Answer (score 0):

With Express Checkout you can use the SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID parameter in the request to specify the email address or account ID of a 3rd party and the money will go directly to them.  No need for anything special outside of that.

Alternatively, you can use the [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/).

Comment: Thanks...however, I already tried SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID before asking (by specifying PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID). What worked though is specifying a SUBJECT parameter which is undocumented.

Comment: Well, I use it that way quite a bit myself, so I know that works.  You could have had something wrong with your request.  SUBJECT would only work if you've granted API Permissions for your app from the 3rd party.

Comment: I have 2 paypal accounts. I haven't granted any permission or access of one for the other. The subject param is able to put dollars into the other by logging in as another test user but it is not able to do much else - example, refunds are not allowed.